# Reactive web services and backpressure

Tags: web-services, streaming, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, reactive-streams

I'm studying reactive streams concepts. I understand it's non-blocking processing of demand-driven, push-based data streams.

The central concept is *backpressure*, which means the consumer controls the flow of data from upstream producer.

How is the backpressure implemented at service boundary? Let's say I have web service which returns large collection of data. Clients should be able to *stream* the return payload. How to make the service reactive in this context? Is it possible to define reactive REST service? If so, how does the underlying HTTP protocol support streaming?

Comment: HTTP doesn't support backpressure. WebFlux provide only *visible* reactive system over HTTP. If you want to archive the real reactive, you may want to use RSocket.